# How many good answers before question asking is restored?

Tags: support

## How many good answers before question asking is restored?

I have been banned from asking questions. 
SE meta said that good answers can get question asking restored.

> Good answers get upvotes, which indicate that you have made positive
>   contributions. This may help you get to a point where you will be
>   allowed to ask questions again.
>
> [Question ban – what exactly are "positive contributions"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224001/question-ban-what-exactly-are-positive-contributions)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do in my specific case to show my positive contribution to the site to get my question ban lifted?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5157/what-can-i-do-in-my-specific-case-to-show-my-positive-contribution-to-the-site-t)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure the answer is correct on that particular point. The help center article does not state anything which suggests answers have any effect on question bans whatsoever.

In fact, the article **specifically** mentions questions only and that even a single good **question** may lift the ban. This makes sense since both there is an answer ban as well and a general "new posting ban" would make more sense if one could prevent or lift question bans by good answers and vice versa.

Therefore, I'd assume the correct answer to the title question is

### You cannot lift a question ban by posting positively received answers at all.

Comment: So then the SE Meta answer is a lie?

Comment: @polcott It's an answer by a regular user on a regular SE network, so I'd say they are simply mistaken. I do not claim my own post to be word of god here either, though.

Comment: @polcott To be more specific, the user used to be an elected moderator just as I am on two communities, but not an employee of SE/SO Inc. This means the takes may be wrong and only employees may definitely answer that question.

Comment: The conventional advice of fixing your bad questions does not seem to apply in my case. One of these -4 questions is now inaccessible to me and two of the other ones have been closed. I couldn't get a definite answer about whether fixing closed questions would help.

Comment: From my point of view the key problem with all three of these questions is ONLY that they stretch the boundary of conventional wisdom. At least now because of you I know that the hidden basis for the rejection of my ideas is anchored in foundationalism.

Comment: Can I get out of my question ban by answers? 

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253116/can-i-get-out-of-my-question-ban-by-answers/253118#253118